# introduction book to SAS

Tags: sas

I just wonder if you can recommended me any book about introduction to SAS? I have programming background in OOp in C++ and java. some people recommend me:

```
Applied Statistics and the SAS Programming Language
The Little SAS Book: A Primer
SAS Applications Programming
Applied Statistics and the SAS Programming Language
```

any suggestion? thx

Comment: What's wrong with the 4 suggestions you already have?  :-P

Comment: @DaveS.I don't know which one should I buy

Comment: Hi Neil, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting in the future - this sort of question isn't really appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Little SAS Book is a great resource. I still reference it from time to time, especially since I was away from the language for a while. Not familiar with the other books in the list.

Comment: okay, i'll get that book. thx

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the book references you already have, remember to use the documentation available on the SAS Support web site.  If you are new to SAS, I'd very much recommend reading the **SAS Concepts** book.  [Here is the 9.3 version](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm) of the book.  Also read the **SAS Companion** for your operating system.

Specific documentation can be a bit hard to find because there are so many different components.  Look around the [main documentation site](http://support.sas.com/documentation/) for much, much more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend the SAS Certification Prep Guide: Base Programming for SAS 9 (now on third edition).

This gives you a thorough grounding in all the fundamental concepts of the data step, and gives you practice questions to test what you have learned.  It is also great preparation for the SAS Certification exam.

Comment: SAS Programming by example by Ron Cody.